# Matlab - Access the output a function inside another function

Tags: matlab, function, output

I am trying to access the output of a function from another function. I have the following function:

```
function f = doSomething
f = 5+6;
```

In another function I'm calling doSomething as follows:

```
doSomething;
```

Is there a way to get the value of `f`? I want to read the output of doSomething and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

> output = doSomething();

to store the result to the variable "output", and

> fprintf('%d\n',output);

to display it.